# Part name identification help - WinkHaus side locks?

Tags: doors

I have a WinkHaus doors that can tilt and turn, and when you luck them there are pins bon the door that slide into these "pegs" that are mounted inside rhe door frame. Anyone knows their name? Do they have a generic name?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to WinkHaus, I believe the parts you are talking about are named as follows (quoted material)

> The Winkhaus roller cam
> Cotter pin locking systems are an
> easy-to-install alternative for main or secondary entrance doors made
> of wood or plastic. The lock has up to four additional drawing points
> and thereby guarantees a tighter seal and improved protection against
> opening of the door by force.
> The roller cams, adjustable manually,
> allow the door situation to be adapted accordingly and thus facilitate
> optimum locking. This allows door design tolerances to be balanced
> out.
> Winkhaus mushroom pin
> The mushroom pins slide behind the
> security keep when the door is bolted. This prevents the door leaf and
> frame from being pulled apart horizontally. The contact pressure can
> be conveniently adjusted using a hexagon socket. This guarantees easy
> bolting and high door movement in the frame - a major plus for
> security and tightness at the door element.